# EKEvent broken in iOS5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ekevent

I had my EKEvent working fine and posting to Calendar.app perfectly in iOS4. Now all of a sudden it doesnt work in iOS5 or 6..?

I've searched the web for hours and i cant seem to find a solution?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmm"];

NSLog(@"eventDateTime: %@", eventDateTime);

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"201207202030"];

eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
//defaultCalendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
venueEvent  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
//venueEvent.calendar = Calendar;
venueEvent.title     = event.name;
venueEvent.location = @"The Blvd Tavern";
venueEvent.startDate = date;
venueEvent.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:14400  sinceDate:venueEvent.startDate];
EKAlarm *eventAlarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-28800];
NSArray *alarmArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:eventAlarm1, nil];
venueEvent.alarms = alarmArray;
[venueEvent setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
//[venueEvent setCalendar:defaultCalendar];
NSError *err = [[NSError alloc] init];
[eventStore saveEvent:venueEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err]; 

NSLog(@"%@", err);
```

I keep gettin this error log when i run this code

> Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=1 "No calendar has been set." UserInfo=0x1cd2a350 {NSLocalizedDescription=No calendar has been set.}

Comment: have you import EvenKit and framework?

Comment: yep! ive traced the problem to [eventStore defaultCalenderForNewEvents], the default no longer allows modifications? is there any way to ask the user to change this?

Comment: the problem is... you should authenticate yourself to access the Calendar. **[you can find more information here about this](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)**. without authentication you can get only `nil` pointers for everything. this is why you got this error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float version = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue];
if(version >= 6.0){        
    EKAuthorizationStatus status = [EKEventStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
    if(status == EKAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined){
        [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
            if(!granted){
                Alert!
            }
        }];
    }else if(status == EKAuthorizationStatusDenied){
        Alert!

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to ask the user for permission to use the calendar before you can modify it. Try this:

`if([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}`

Source: https://jeboyer.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/handling-access-to-calendars-in-ios-6-2/